# EF Core 6 derived DbContext doesn't get connection string from Startup

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have a windows service that listens for status messages from server using socket. This works for sometime when the service is started. After that, it stops receiving new messages.

I have a very basic Web API to track time for the several hourly workers at my company. In my `Startup.cs` I have an `AddDbContext` method

```cs
services.AddDbContext<TimeCardsContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

I get the configuration string through

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("TimeConnection").
```

From the documentation, and hours googling, it seems that my derived `DbContext` simply has to have constructor that takes a `DbContextOptions`, like so:

```cs
public TimeCardsContext (DbContextOptions options) : base (options)
{

}
```

As I understand it, that should be enough to inject the `DbContext` created in `Startup`. This, however, simply doesn't work. When I debug, I get a null reference to the connection string.

I must really not understand how this is supposed to work.

Some google searches suggest I use the `OnConfiguring` method in my `DbContext` class, but in every example they hard code the connection string in the method. That just ain't right!

Suggestions appreciated!

**EDITED** to add:

Here is the entire relevant part of my Startup.cs

```
namespace TimeCardsNg2
{

    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        public static string connectionString { get; set; }

        public Startup (IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public Startup () {}
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString ("TimeConnect");

            services.AddDbContext<TimeCardsContext>(options => 
                                                    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                                                            .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information));

            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddScoped<DbContext, TimeCardsContext>();
            services.AddScoped<IWorkerService, WorkerService>();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1"
                            , new OpenApiInfo
                            {
                                Title = "TimeCardsNg2 API",
                                Version = "v1"
                            ,
                                Description = "Testing Swagger"
                            });
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if(env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: default, "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json"
                                 , "Zomato API V1");

                // To serve SwaggerUI at application's root page, set the RoutePrefix property to an empty string.
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });
        }
    }

}
```

And, here's the relevant portion of my context class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

#nullable disable

namespace TimeCardsNg2.Models
{
    public partial class TimeCardsContext : DbContext
    {
        private IConfiguration configuration { get; set; }
        protected string connectionString { get; set; }

        public TimeCardsContext()
        {
        }

        public TimeCardsContext(DbContextOptions<TimeCardsContext> options) : base(options)
        { }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {

        }

        public virtual DbSet<TimeCard> TimeCards { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
```

I hope this will make my situation a little clearer.

Forgot to add a nice picture:
[image]

Please notice the connectionString is null.

Comment: What format is your connection string in your config? It should be as `{ "ConnectionStrings": { "TimeConnection": "..." } }`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings)

Comment: The fact that you are not getting correct connection string from settings/configuration has nothing to do with EF Core, as this is outside its scope. All EF Core requires is correctly configured `DbContextOptions`. How you do that, and where are you getting the connection string is up to you. So ignore the EF Core part (it is fine) and just figure out why you are getting `null` connection string.

Comment: Problem might be in your connection string.

Comment: Can I infer from these comments, that DoI from Startup.cs to my TimeCardsContext should work basically out of the box? My connection string is fine. I use the same connection string (copy and pasted) in my LinqPad6 application. Also, the appsettings.json file is formatted exactly as crgolden shows.

Comment: Hi Ivan Stoev. I have added a DbContext, with options, in the Startup.cs. What am I missing?